# Create a new row through a rendered React component

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I used `cellRenderer` with `frameworkComponents` to render a button component as a column.

```
import InsertNodeBtnRender from "./HierarchyButtons/insertRowBtn.jsx";

columnDefs: [
        {
          lockPosition: true,
          cellRenderer: "insertBtnRender",
          // cellClass: 'locked-col',
          maxWidth: 60,
          // suppressNavigable: true,
        },
        { field: "jobTitle" },
        { field: "employmentType" },
      ],
      frameworkComponents: {
        insertBtnRender: InsertNodeBtnRender,
      },
```

```
class InsertNodeBtn extends Component {

  btnClickedHandler() {
  // I have access to "this.props.node" for setting data to EXISTING rows
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.btnClickedHandler()}>+</button>;
  }
}

export default InsertNodeBtn;
```

Within the handler in the above component, I am able to manipulate the existing row node with the props property (such as use `this.props.node.setData()`). However, I simply want to ADD a new row to the grid with some of the data fields based on the current cell.

[image: Pressing the "+" button should create a new row with the same data values]

How would I go about this? There doesn't seem to be provided method within the API that allows me to do this and is accessible within the component event handler. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#gsc.tab=0

***TLDR; After pressing the "+" button. How do I add a NEW row to the grid?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GriApi.applyTransaction({ add: newItems })` to add new rows to the grid. See [update-transaction](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update-transactions/) section for more info. Here is an example:

```
import React from "react";

let i = 0;

function createNewRowData({ orgHierarchy, employmentType }) {
  const boss = orgHierarchy[orgHierarchy.length - 1];
  const newData = {
    jobTitle: "Minion",
    employmentType,
    orgHierarchy: orgHierarchy.concat(boss + "'s Minion " + ++i)
  };
  return newData;
}

export default function InsertNodeBtnRender(props) {
  const { api, columnApi, data } = props;
  const onAdd = () => {
    const newItems = [createNewRowData(data)];

    api.applyTransaction({ add: newItems });
    columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns();
  };

  return <button onClick={onAdd}>+</button>;
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63946523/ag-grid-react-create-a-new-row-through-a-rendered-react-component]